# What set are these LEGO assemblies from?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

[image]

I bought a lot of second hand LEGO  - it was an utter bargain at £10 - and have identified loads of different sets, however this part is infuriating me as I can't identify what it could be part of. Perhaps a submarine? It looks like a periscope in the middle and I'm sure it had at one point 6-8 legs sticking out on the sides.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Set 75013 Umbaran MHC (Mobile Heavy Cannon)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75013-1) , based on the leg shape and the Dark Red 1x1 Headlight Bricks.

[image]

Comment: Oh my! That is amazing!! Virtual hug coming your way! Thank you so so much!

Comment: Howdy Caz, welcome to Bricks.  It'd be good to click the checkbox by the answer to "accept it".  It is even better than a virtual hug.

Comment: @Caz See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hope I've accepted it right ?